# How to store data objects that use 2 keys to look up a value

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, lookup

I need to tie 3 types of things together:

1. an enum (state)
2. another enum (type of function)
3. a function reference.

The context of my project is that I have a video game state machine that exists in a single class. I have several switch statements that I am trying to replace. Each state has a set of functions associated with it, such as Enter() and Exit().

In English, I want to say, "for ___ state, call ___ type of function" and then it calls the actual function. For example, I'd like to do something like this:

Lookup [states.attacking] [stateFunctions.enter];

where this would return a call to "void Attacking_Enter()"

Answer (score 2):

You could use a

```
Dictionary<states, Dictionary<stateFunctions, Action>> Lookup = new Dictionary<states, Dictionary<stateFunctions, Action>>();
```

so you can look up and execute via e.g.

```
// First Key finds the inner dictionary
// Second key finds the action in the inner dictionary
// ? makes sure you don't get NullReferenceExceptions (just in case)
// Invoke() finally executed the stored action
Lookup[states.enter][stateFunctions.attack]?.Invoke();
```

---

Careful while filling it: Make sure to initialize the inner `Dictionary`(s) before adding elements to it e.g.

```
Lookup[states.enter] = new Dictionary<stateFunctions, Action>();
Lookup[states.enter][stateFunctions.attack] = Attacking_Enter;
```

Or initialize them all in one go like e.g.

```
private void Initialize ()
{
    Lookup = new Dictionary<states, Dictionary<stateFunctions, Action>>
    {
        {states.enter, new Dictionary<stateFunctions, Action>
                       { 
                           {stateFunctions.attack, Attacking_Enter}, 
                           ...
                       }
        },
        ...
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var dict = Dictionary<Dictioanry<T1, T2>, T3>();
```

where T1, T2 and T3 are your desired data types.

Comment: Wouldn't you want your 2nd dictionary as the value instead of the key?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=netcore-3.1)

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<T1, T2>, T3>();
```

Or Class object which implement [GetHashCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netcore-3.1) if needed

```
var dict = new Dictionary<ClassObj, T3>();
```

Comment: Tuple does not support such query as Lookup [states.attacking] [stateFunctions.enter]